# html5 boilerplate issue in chrome 16.0.912.63

Tags: html5boilerplate

Does anyone else experience issues with html5 boilerplate with chrome 16.0.912.63?  Just downloaded it and when I open index.html it takes about 40 seconds to render.  Looking in Chrome developer tools it appears that the protocol relative url

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
```

is causing the issue.  If I add the `http:` to the URL it seems to retrieve jquery in a reasonable amount of time, but then the modernizr.js script has issues retrieving ga.js.

I assume there are many people using boilerplate with Chrome, but I didn't see anything on the boilerplate site that indicates this a common problem.  Is it possible I have configured something incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think boilerplate explain this issue here http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/FAQs/. They recommend to use local dev server instead of using file:/// schema to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix systems go to your terminal and navigate to your project and type:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

index.html page will be on http://localhost:8000

On Windows, copy the [Mongoose executable](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) to your project folder and launch it. index.html page will be on http://localhost:8080